# Emails going to inbox but spam message are displaying

Tags: php

I'm trying to send email from my domain. Mail is delivering properly. But it showing some message mentioning that the delivered message is spam. Please help me to overcome that problem. This is the message I got Be careful with this message

> This may be a spoofed message. The message claims to have been sent
>   from your account, but Gmail couldn’t verify the actual source. Avoid
>   clicking links or replying with sensitive information, unless you are
>   sure you actually sent this message. (No need to reset your password,
>   the real sender does not actually have access to your account!)

```
    <?php
   if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$email_to = "info@maxwell.com";
$email_subject = "Your email subject line";
$name = $_POST['name'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$email_from = $_POST['mail'];

$email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";
$email_message .= "Name: ".$name."\n";
$email_message .= "Email: ".$email_from."\n";
$email_message .= "message: ".$message."\n";
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
if(mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers)){
  ?>
  <script>
    window.location.href="contact.php?success";
  </script>
  <?php
  // print("Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon.");
}
else{
  ?>
  <script>
    window.location.href="contact.php?fail";
  </script>
     <?php
}
  // print("fail");
  }
?>

<form method="post" >
        <div class="form">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Your Name">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 form-group">
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" name="mail" placeholder="E-mail Address">
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 form-group">
                    <textarea name="message" placeholder="Message..."></textarea>
                    <!-- <input type="submit" value="SEND MESSAGE" class="btn-black bounce-top"> -->
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 form-group">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn-black bounce-top" name="submit" value="SEND MESSAGE">
                </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

[image: This is the email result]

Comment: Please take a look at stuff like rDNS, DKIM, DMARC, SPF... (and so on, and so on) I think this is an interesting item: https://www.purehacking.com/blog/angus-strom/the-art-of-email-spoofing-protection

Answer (score 3):

In order to avoid such situation. You can follow the following suggestions:

**A Simple Implementation Example**

```
<?php
mail("recipient@recipient.com", "Message", "A simple message.", "From: The Sender <sender@sender.com>");
?>
```

**4 Ways To Make Your PHP mail() Emails Less Spammy**

1. Use Headers
2. The Message Sender Domain and Server Domain Should Match
3. Be Sure to Properly Use the Content-type Attribute
4. Verify That Your Server Is Not Blacklisted

***Detailed Explanation:***

**1. Use Headers**

```
<?php
$headers .= "Reply-To: The Sender <sender@sender.com>\r\n";
$headers .= "Return-Path: The Sender <sender@sender.com>\r\n";
$headers .= "From: The Sender <senter@sender.com>\r\n";
?>
```

Be sure to replace the fourth parameter with the $headers variable as shown below.

```
<?php
mail("recipient@recipient.com", "Message", "A simple message.", $headers);
?>
```

**2. The Message Sender Domain and Server Domain Should Match**

Spammers are notorious for sending emails from one server and trying to make the recipient believe that it came from somewhere else. So if you are sending an email from example@example.com, it is a good idea the the script reside on example.com.

**3. Be Sure to Properly Use the Content-type Attribute**

The Content-type attribute enables a message sender to say whether or not an email is plain text  or html, or whether it has attachments. Obviously, the easiest to use content type is text/plain. You just add your text as shown in the simple example, and you are done. But when you use the other content types, additional pieces might be expected. For example, with the text/html content type, an html body tag is expected. Not having this tag could result in your email being marked as spam.

**4. Verify That Your Server Is Not Blacklisted**

When a server is blacklisted, it means that that server has identified as one that has been sending a lot of spam. This results in recipient mail servers rejecting or filtering any mail that is received from that server.

So if your mail is not being received it is a good idea to verify that your server has not been blacklisted. This goes for both shared and dedicated servers. In a shared environment, it is common for other users on the server to be sending out spam. And in a dedicated environment, spammers may have found a way to exploit a vulnerability in a server or contact form to send out spam. So it is easy for either type of server to be blacklisted.

Comment: To add some color here -- google is VERY skeptical of new mail servers, so your IP likely doesn't yet have a good reputation yet. It can take 6 months to 'warm up' an IP, which you do by sending a lot of good emails. This is one reason why email service providers have become so popular -- managing this opaque aspect of running an email server is pretty tough, and usually its just cheaper to outsource it. The less your emails bounce and get marked as spam the better your reputation will get.

Answer (score -3):

If you want a solution sure to not get marked as spam, look into Amazon's SES service. You will likely never exceed free tier pricing, and with a bit of configuration, you'll hit inboxes at much higher rates.

Comment: This question is about a spoofing warning message, not being marked as spam.

Comment: Funny, I searched for this issue because I am using AWS SES from an AWS Lambda function and sent a test email from my gmail.com address to myself via AWS SES and gmail displays this same warning message. It's a brand new gmail address and hardly used it.